# @font-face not working with specific font

Tags: css, font-face

So I can't get the @font-face to work with a specific font. Is it because of the font-file or am I doing something wrong?

link to site: http://carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/

path to font-file: ftp://ftp.carlpapworth.com//friday-quiz/fonts/Lobster_1.3.otf
css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: lobster;
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/Lobster_1.3.otf');
}
```

My other fonts that I call in works fine, as you can see.
Cheers for any help.
C.

Answer (score 0):

The page mentioned is displayed by Firefox without any `@font-face` fonts. The network log does not even show any attempts at fetching fonts. Looking at the Firefox error console (or using the W3C CSS Validator) reveals that the at-rules are malformed: they start with

```
@font-faceÂ {
```

So they are ignored. The odd `Â` might result from some character encoding gone wrong, but anyway fixing this should be the first move. If problems remain, please try to post the simplest possible document where the problem still appears. Also note that .otf format is not supported by IE and is not optimal font format for the web either; consider using [FontSquirrel @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) for cross-browser functionality.

Comment: Well two of my other fonts are working fine with `@font-face`, and the code is the same... so it is all quite weird

Comment: Are you sure you are testing the page you mentioned, http://carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/ ? On which browser(s)?

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lobster';
    src: url("fonts/lobster.woff") format("woff"),
         url("fonts/lobster.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("fonts/lobster.svg#webfontszsn4DPI") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Even though it is an .otf?

Comment: Well i mean that you probly should offer more then just one type to make it work on all brouwsers.